# discrete-event simulation example

Tags: c#, events, simulation

I want to perform a discrete-event simulation in C#. I want three balls rolling on the screen simultaneously following a random walk pattern. At time 1 ball one should appear and start rolling, at time 5, ball 2 and at time 10, ball 3 should appear. When any two balls come enough closer the color of balls should change (as long as they stay close).

I am very new to discrete event simulation, and i want to understand, how we do it in C# programming? what steps are required in creating the model. I know graphics and other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Timer (drag one from the Toolbox over to your form in the designer, or instantiate it in code if you prefer).  Double click the timer to set a `_Tick` event in your code which will fire every N milliseconds (the `.Interval` property of the timer governs this).  Set the `.Interval` to 1000 (1 second), and use objects that keep track of their own position in X and Y coordinates.

Use a `Random` object to generate the direction of the next position change of the ball, and within the `_Tick` event of the timer, update the position variables for each of the balls.

Using raw threads is a possibility, too, but the Timer gives you some of that power without having to manage everything yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did that using timer and then using threads. Both solutions are working, although threads have some strange behaviors. I have read some theory about discrete-event simulation and it states Components of a Discrete-Event Simulation are Clock, Events List, Random-Number Generators, Statistics. In the balls example, how the queues would be used / beneficial? Secondly, how to keep track whether two balls came close, do I need to run another timer event for that?

Comment: @OsmanKhalid I'm not sure how you are supposed to use a queue.  I suppose you could use them to release the balls at the proper intervals in the beginning.  To see if two balls collide, check to see if their coordinates overlap after you've done all of the ball movements within the `_Tick` method.

Comment: see underscores answer, what you are describing is not DES because it is using threads and timers.

Comment: @BenPage I'm far from an expert (and this was a long time ago), but `Using operating system timers or threads is NOT the way the discrete event simulations should work` doesn't seem to have a lot of evidence behind it.  With the discrete intervals the OP was describing, I'm not sure why doing it with timers would be a problem.  If they were attempting to simulate a braking system in an automobile, I'd agree that any time jitter coming from the OS could be problematic, but this ball rolling example seems to be more of a "toy" problem.

Answer (score 6):

New comers be advised:

Using operating system timers or threads is NOT the way the discrete event simulations should work. Using one of these as a building block might be misleading or a plain wrong.

- Read the wikipedia article first about [Discrete Event Simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation) (DES)
- There are" models" so called "formalisms" that mathematically proven to work in event simulation. You need to implement one (for example [DEVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEVS)).
- You may want to look at some listed DES [List of discrete event simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_discrete_event_simulation_software) software at the wikipedia.
- Also you may find useful [sigmawiki](http://sigmawiki.com/sigma/index.php?title=Main_Page) (programs,examples, tutorials) about DES. [SharpSim](http://sharpsim.codeplex.com/) and [React.NET](http://reactnet.sourceforge.net/) are DES implementations in C#.